# Can't change JQuery lightSlider Slides by element index number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

I'm building this page:
https://yuyotest.000webhostapp.com/design.html

The code is not ready, I'm still testing a couple of things so bare with me with the position of the scripts haha.

Well the thing is that at the end of the 1st section, there are 4 logos. Whenever one of those logos is clicked, a modal will popup with a slider (JQuery lightSlider) in it.

I`m having console errors when trying to click one of the logos and make the slider show the slide number of the logo nth:child clicked. Getting the child number is workin great with `.index(this) + 1);`
but making the slider display the slide number "index+1 slide" only works one time, if I try again, the console says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'goToSlide' of undefined.

Any thoughts on how to solve this? I thought about reseting the `slider.goToSlide(slide_n);`function  but honestly don't know how to do that :(

Thanks in advance!

```
$(".design-logos").click(function() {

        var slide_n = ($('.design-logos').index(this) + 1);
        

        if ($("#light-slider").hasClass("lightSlider")) {
            
        } else {
            var slider = $("#light-slider").lightSlider({
                item: 1,
                loop: true,
                speed: 1,
                enableDrag: false,
            });
        }     

        slider.goToSlide(slide_n);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codes are kinda in a mess. I have made many changes but hopefully it will work when you substitute your code in your fourth `<script></script>` tag in the page with code below:

```
var slider;
            $(document).ready(function() {


            // modal in // 

            function modalIn() {

                $(".jp-modal-wrapper").show();
                $('body').addClass("body-ovf");

                setTimeout(function() {

                    $(".projects-main-slider").addClass("projects-main-slider-in");

                    $('.blackdrop').addClass("blackdrop-in");

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('.jp-inner-modal').addClass("jp-inner-modal-in");
                    }, 350);

                    $('.carousel-item.active img').lazy({
                        effect: "fadeIn",
                        effectTime: 1000,
                        threshold: 0
                    });

                }, 10);

            };


            // modal off //

            function modalOff() {

                $('.jp-inner-modal').removeClass("jp-inner-modal-in");

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.blackdrop').removeClass("blackdrop-in");
                }, 500);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".jp-modal-wrapper").hide();
                    $('body').removeClass("body-ovf");
                }, 1000);

            };

            $(".blackdrop").click(function() {
                modalOff();
            });

            $('body').keydown(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                    modalOff();
                }
            });

            // modal off //
            
                

            $(".design-logos").click(function() {

                var slide_n = ($('.design-logos').index(this) + 1);                
                

                // modal in //                     
                modalIn();

                setTimeout(function() {


                    if ($("#light-slider").hasClass("lightSlider")) {
                        
                    } else {
                        slider = $("#light-slider").lightSlider({
                            item: 1,
                            loop: true,
                            speed: 1,
                            enableDrag: false,
                        });
                    }

                                  
                    setTimeout(function() {     
                    slider.goToSlide(slide_n);

                }, 301);

                //else

            }, 5);

            function fadeSlideIn() {
                    $(".next").addClass("disable-button");
                    $(".projects-main-slider").addClass("projects-main-slider-mov");
            }

                function fadeSlideOut() {
                    $(".next").removeClass("disable-button");
                    $(".projects-main-slider").removeClass("projects-main-slider-mov");
                }

                $(".gotoslide").click(function () {

                    slider.goToSlide(2);
                });





            $(".next").click(function () {
                    fadeSlideIn();
                    const curSliderInd = slider.getCurrentSlideCount();
                    const nextSlide = curSliderInd == 4 ? 1 : curSliderInd + 1;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        let curSliderInd = slider.getCurrentSlideCount();
                        slider.goToSlide(nextSlide);
                    }, 301);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        fadeSlideOut();
                    }, 302);
            });

            $(".prev").click(function () {
                    fadeSlideIn();
                    const curSliderInd = slider.getCurrentSlideCount();
                    const nextSlide = curSliderInd == 1 ? 4 : curSliderInd - 1;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        
                        slider.goToSlide(nextSlide);
                    }, 301);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        fadeSlideOut();
                    }, 302);
                });
            });






        });
```

Comments on your code:

First, your code failed because the else block

```
if ($("#light-slider").hasClass("lightSlider")) {
            
        } else {
            var slider = $("#light-slider").lightSlider({
                item: 1,
                loop: true,
                speed: 1,
                enableDrag: false,
            });
        }
```

is not executed once element `light-slider` got the class `lightSlider`, that is when one of the logos get clicked first time. But `slider` is declared within this block thus it becomes `undefined` if the else block is not executed first. Giving `slider` a global reference solves the problem. This solution is nasty, but I don't have time to dive in that jQuery extension to find an optimal workaround.

Second, after playing with your page a while, I found the behaviors of `goToPrevSlide()` and `goToNextSlide()` methods are somehow not as expectation. Thus, I have edited the calls to these methods in callbacks of buttons `next` and `prev`.

Third, you have put some of the definitions of your callbacks in a `setTimeout`!  Maybe that is merely due to carelessness and I unwrapped them anyway. There are other defects in format which I have no time to correct. You may need to correct them to avoid their later revenge.

Comment: THANKS A LOT, I honestly appreciate your time and help!!!     
Yes I know is a mess haha, aside me been a js newbie, I'm trying to figure the functions out!  I quite didn't understand how giving slider a global reference works, I'll have to look info about that.  Loved how you edited the calls for next and prev! lastly I the setTimeout callbacks to prevent the animations to interfere with the light-slider events.  But I`m working on all of yours comments and warnings! So thanks a lot again you have truly helped me a lot! ♥